# SQL Query to get Merchant Name with max date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to achieve the below but not sure how to go about it any query pointing in the right direction will be a great help.

Tables: I have three tables below#

```
Merchant(MerchantId, Name, Date), 
MerchantCategory(MerchantId, CategoryId), 
Category (CategoryId, Name)
```

How to return `category name`, `Merchant count`,`Merchant name` with `max date`

Comment: It would be great if you update your question with data and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the requirement I understand that there should be 1 row per category, that the number of merchants should be shown and that the name of the merchant with the most recent date should be shown.

I have prepared a query below that generates some sample data and provides the result intended as I understand it.

The way this works is that the merchant volume is calculated by joining the merchant category table on to the category table and then counting the merchant id's per category. The name is trickier and requires using outer apply that per category (per row) works out the top 1 name in the merchant table ordered by the max(date) desc

I hope this helps, any questions please let me know.

```
declare @Merchant table (
    MerchantId int,
    Name nvarchar(25),
    Date Date
);

declare @MerchantCategory table (
    MerchantId int,
    CategoryId int
);

declare @Category table (
    CategoryId int,
    Name nvarchar(25)
);

insert into @Merchant (MerchantId, Name, Date)
values
(1, 'Lucy', '2019-01-05'),
(2, 'Dave', '2019-01-30'),
(3, 'Daniel' ,'2019-02-01');

insert into @MerchantCategory (MerchantId, CategoryId)
values
(1, 4),
(1, 5),
(2, 4),
(3, 5);

insert into @Category (CategoryId, Name)
values
(4, 'Cat1'), 
(5, 'Cat2');

select c. Name, max(m.name) as MaxMerchantName, count(distinct mc2.merchantid) as Merchantvol from @Category c
left join @MerchantCategory mc2 on c.CategoryId=mc2.CategoryId
outer apply (select top 1 name, max(date) as date from @Merchant m inner join @MerchantCategory mc on m.MerchantId=mc.MerchantId where c.CategoryId=mc.CategoryId group by Name order by max(date) desc) m
group by c.Name;
```

Comment: this is bringing the correct result, just wondering if the query needs to be this complex ? Thanks for the amazing effort.

Comment: Hi Sina, most of that query is generating the sample data. The fetching of the name for the max date is a bit tricky because of the 1:1 mapping between the categoryid and the merchantid. If the answer has solved your issue could you please mark as accepted  I am more than happy to answer further questions.

Comment: It wont allow me to vote it up sorry, my credibility is low, not sure how else to thank you oh great lord of SQL

Comment: There should be a check box next each answer which allows you to mark as accepted. That would be thanks enough.

Answer (score 0):

I would have expected to see your efforts..

so am going against SO principles @ the moment..

try this:

```
select c.Name as category_name, count(*) as Merchant_Count, m.Name as Merchant_Name, max(Date)  from
Merchant m join MerchantCategory mc 
on m.MerchantId = mc.MerchantId
join Category c 
on mc.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
group by c.Name, m.Name
```